# How can I join two scopes with or condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 scopes :

```
  scope :active, -> { joins(:poi).merge(Poi.active) }
  scope :valided_by_user, -> { joins(:poi).merge(Poi.valided_by_user) }
```

I would like to have a scope "displayed" that return all records who are active OR valided_by_user

How can I join this two scopes with or condition ?

Comment: How are `Poi.active` and `Poi.valided_by_user` defined?

Comment: They are defined in Poi.rb :

  scope :active, -> { where('statut = ?', 1) }
  scope :valided_by_user, -> { where('statut = ?', 2) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do as following

```
scope :active_or_valided_by_user, -> { active.or(valided_by_user) }
```